# Changing web Page URL in CCNet Email

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Currently when we get build result mails from CCNet the web page link in mail body points to a wrong URL.

Please let me know how to correct this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to correctly set the WebUrl information in the project configuration. That's what is used for the email link.

See http://ccnet.sourceforge.net/CCNET/Project%20Configuration%20Block.html